# How to move list of files from different directories to new directory using bash

Tags: bash, cat, xargs, mv

I used `find ./busd/ -type f -iname '*.pdf' | less` to look for `.pdf` files on my second drive and there are hundreds of results from different subdirectories but I only needed to `copy/move selection of pdf files` to new directory.

I copy pasted their paths/filenames to `moveme.txt`.

I am thinking of `cat moveme.txt | xargs command` but i am stocked there. Please help.

I tried `cat moveme.txt | xargs -0 -I % sh -c 'sudo mv -v % /new/directory/'` and failed. How to do this right?

edit:
I like to add that this path/filenames have spaces. Maybe it matters.

excerpt from `moveme.txt`:

```
./busd/0128/csm/sorting/read-ables/linus/CLI/Bash-Beginners-Guide-new.pdf
./busd/0128/csm/3t2/readables/etc/xulin/Shell Scripting.pdf
./busd/0128/csm/dais6/Dearables/assorted/Bash Pocket Reference - Arnold Robbins.pdf
```

Comment: Depending on version of mv, `xargs mv -t /new/directory < moveme.txt`

Comment: Thanks @Shawn i have mv (GNU coreutils) 9.0. I will try this.

Comment: @Shawn Im having "mv: cannot stat 'filename.pdf': No such file or directory
"

Comment: Sounds like your paths to files aren't resolved from whatever the command's current working directory is.

Comment: Please provide more information like how `moveme.txt` looks like and the full options you used in `find` command.

Comment: @Weihang I just updated my querry with additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting to dry-run printing each **ireversible** `mv` cmd before execution:

```
  awk '{cmd = "mv \"" $0 "\" /new/directory/"; print cmd}' moveme.txt
```

When ready to execute `mv` command:

```
  awk '{cmd = "mv \"" $0 "\" /new/directory/"; system(cmd)}' moveme.txt
```

---

Another option is to transform your `moveme.txt` file into a bash script using `sed` command and inspect `moveme.sh` before execution.

```
  sed -r 's|(^$)|mv "\1" /new/directory/|' moveme.txt > moveme.sh
```

Inspect `moveme.sh` and run it.

```
  chmod a+x ./moveme.sh
  bash ./moveme.sh
```

Comment: The dry-run suggestion is brilliant. I will look into learning awk and sed asap.

Comment: the awk command gave me syntax error.

`awk '{cmd = "sudo cp \"" $0 "\" /new/directory/"; system cmd}' copyfiles.txt`
`awk: cmd. line:1: {cmd = "sudo cp \"" $0 "\" /new/direcory/"; system cmd}`
`awk: cmd. line:1:                                                       ^ syntax error`

Comment: suggesting: awk '{cmd = "sudo cp \"" $0 "\" /new/directory/"; system(cmd)}' . Will fix the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
find ./busd/ -type f -iname '*.pdf' -print0 |
  xargs -0 -P0 sh -c 'mv -v "$@" /new/directory/' sh
```

## Explanation

1. It makes little sense to pipe stdout of `find` to `xargs -0` without `-print0`. The `find` command requires `-print0` option because filenames might have spaces as you mentioned.
2. Using `xargs -I%` would not benefit from the parallelization feature of `xargs -P NUMBER`. `xargs -P0` would utilize all CPU cores.
3. The last `sh` of `sh -c '...' sh` is required for `$0`. It can be arbitrary string but you might want to make a sensible name.

## DIY

```sh
seq 100000 | sed 's/$/.pdf/' | xargs -P0 touch
mkdir -p new/directory
find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' -print0 |
  xargs -0 -P0 sh -c 'mv -v "$@" new/directory/' sh
```

1. Remove `-P0` and see the difference of time costing.
2. Try `xargs -p` or `xargs -t` to see how many arguments `xargs` passes.
3. Try `sh -c 'ruby -e "p ARGV" mv -v "$@" new/directory/'` for debugging. You can use any language you prefer, take `node` for example: `sh -c 'node -e "console.log(process.argv.slice(1))" mv -v "$@" new/directory/'`

Answer (score 0):

as an option, it can be done in one command:

```
find ./busd/ -type f -iname '*.pdf' -exec mv -t /target_directory/ {} +
```

or

```
find ./busd/ -type f -iname '*.pdf' -print -exec mv -t /target_directory/ {} +
```

to print all copying files to terminal